# how to remove cookie in jquery accordion menu when logout

Tags: jquery, menu, refresh, accordion

I am using j query accordion vertical menu. 
Now clicked one menu, then log out. the same clicked menu maintained after login.
i want to refresh menu while login.

Comment: You do realize that there are more than one accordion out there and more than one way to set cookies.

Answer (score 1):

To remove cookie set null

```
$.cookie("name", null);
```

Comment: Do note that you need the jQuery cookie plugin for this: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie